# How to handle SECURE_CODING coverty error with sscanf()?

Tags: c, scanf, secure-coding

Coverty is giving following error for the sscanf():

```
char charnum[15] = "429496725";
char copystrpointer[15] = {0};
int intequal = 0;

/* Event secure_coding:     [VERY RISKY]. Using "sscanf(char const * restrict, char const * restrict, ...)" can cause a buffer overflow when done incorrectly. sscanf() assumes an arbitrarily large string, so callers must use correct precision specifiers or never use sscanf(). Use correct precision specifiers or do your own parsing.*/

sscanf (charnum, "%10s", copystrpointer);

/*Event secure_coding:  [VERY RISKY]. Using "sscanf(char const * restrict, char const * restrict, ...)" can cause a buffer overflow when done incorrectly. sscanf() assumes an arbitrarily large string, so callers must use correct precision specifiers or never use sscanf(). Use correct precision specifiers or do your own parsing.*/

sscanf (charnum, "%4d", &intequal);
```

This error is basically because sscanf() doesn't have a bound for the reading and writing, and it can cross the array limit and cause the program to crash.

As coverty itself mention use the precision specifier to solve this, used width specifier in above example, as per my understanding this should read only 10 byte and write maximum of 10 byte. so it should not cross array bound and should be secure.and in the second example 4 byte is the max as this is the integer range in my unit.

But still coverty error persists. As per my understanding precision specifier is possible only for the float and double format specifier (ex: %f) not for the int (%d).

I can see there are suggestion to use alternative functions to handle this, but wanted to use sscanf() to parse some normal strings.

Please let me know what is this precision specifier that coverty is mentioning? is there a way to handle this error?

Comment: I would have though that the precision specifiers are the 10-part of `%10s`, i.e. that you are already doing this correctly. Coverity does not perform a sound analysis, meaning there can be false positives; this could be such one. It is not easy to recognize from the format string, whether or not you use correct format-strings. Therefore I would guess that Coverity warns nomatter what is in the format string.

Comment: @MortenJensen: Basically is this means coverty is not checking for the width specifier (or any other specifier) which is associated with format specifier? and giving this error for sscanf()? This means we can not resolve this issue accept to not to use sscanf.

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but my assumption is based on two things: 1) it seems you're already 'doing the right thing' with sscanf-format strings, and 2) it is non-trivial to parse the format-strings and decipher types, width etc. from those format-strings. Pure speculation on my part. If you need certainty, I suggest you contact Synopsys (or whoever owns Coverity).